# Show whether or not the Lebesgue Theorem applies. Does $\int \int_Af(x,y)dxdy$ exist?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $A = (0, 1) \times (0, 1)$ and $f : A \to \mathbb{R}$ where $$f(x, y) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{x−y} &\text{ if } x \neq y \\
            x &\text{if } x = y
\end{cases}$$

I have this piecewise function and am trying to answer the question above but am not sure how to .

Comment: Like all piecewise integrands, have you integrated on each piece: the upper triangle, the diagonal, and the lower triangle of $A$?

Comment: Which Lebesgue's Theorem does this refer to ?

Answer (score 0):

If the integral exists, then we can apply Fubini theorem, that is integrate on a line (x or y = constant).  But the line integral is notoriously non existent, so the integral does not exist.